# I want to include a go file that I have generated but the go compiler is stating that "package example is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/example)"

Tags: go, swig

I have a file, `example.go` that I want to include in my main.go file. But my IDE and go tool are both complaining when I try to do this.

VS Code Error:

```
could not import example (cannot find package "example" in any of 
    /usr/local/go/src/example (from $GOROOT)
    /root/go/src/example (from $GOPATH))
```

When I run `go run cmd/my_project/main.go` I get the following error from Go tool:

```
cmd/my_project/main.go:4:2: package example is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/example)
```

My project structure is as follows.

```
pet_project
├── cmd
│   └── my_project
│       ├── example
│       │   ├── example.go
│       │   ├── hello.pb.cc
│       │   ├── hello.pb.h
│       │   └── hello_wrap.cxx
│       ├── main.go
│       └── main_test.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
```

Contents of go.mod:

```
module my_project

go 1.19

require google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.1


require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.5.0 // indirect
)
```

The contents of the main.go file, in this file I'm trying to call the code in `example.go`.

```
package main

import (
    "example"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var p example.Person
    p.Dob = 20
    example.Handle(p)
}
```

The contents of example.go are:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* This file was automatically generated by SWIG (https://www.swig.org).
* Version 4.1.1
*
* Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing - modify
* the SWIG interface file instead.
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

// source: hello.i

package example

/*
#define intgo swig_intgo
typedef void *swig_voidp;

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

... omitted for brevity
```

Below are the Go environment variables:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build578899875=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I have tried running `go install` or `go build` and they both fail with the above error.

I have also changed the import of to "cmd/my_project/example" and ran go mod tidy but still face the same error.

Comment: @J.Titus  That didn't help

Comment: Import using: `"my_project/cmd/my_project/example"`.  The first `my_project` is the module name. The `/cmd/my_project/example` is the path within the module.   See https://go.dev/doc/code for a tutorial on the subject.